# Automatic function naming

Tags: ida, static-analysis, memory, strings, functions

I'ld like to know how to bulk rename functions in IDA, based on some condition.

Example:
Rename all functions to Foo_XYZ where the function accesses a certain static variable, for example : dword_12345.

This would help me a lot, because I know that address would be only accessed from functions that can be associated with some logic/functionality in the application.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The IDAScope plugin has similar functionality to rename functions based on the Windows API functions they are calling. You can find a standalone script here that does that http://hooked-on-mnemonics.blogspot.fr/2012/06/automated-generic-function-naming-in.html it should give you an idea how to implement what you are looking for.

Answer (score 4):

You can write an IDC script to do this:

[IDA Online Help - IDC Language](https://www.hex-rays.com/products/ida/support/idadoc/157.shtml)